# Segmentation Fault Example not giving Segmentation Fault

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, flags

I'm trying some segfault examples but none of them is causing the error.

Source code from: http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html

The example is the following:

```
1 : #include <stdio.h>
2 : #include <stdlib.h>

3 : int main(int argc, char **argv)
4 : {
5 :   char *buf;
6 :
7 :   buf = malloc(1<<31);
8 :
9 :   fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
10:   printf("%s\n", buf);
11:
12:   return 1;
13: }
```

The first step is to compile the program with debugging flags:

```
prompt> gcc -g segfault.c
```

Now we run the program:

```
prompt > ./a.out
Hello World!
Segmentation fault
prompt >
```

---

However, the above example is running without segfault in my Ubuntu. I think it is something related to gcc options, but I could not find out what is causing this. When I run in a different distro the problem occurs.

This is the output of my gcc:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i486-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1' 
    --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs 
    --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared 
    --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib 
    --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix 
    --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-nls 
    --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc
    --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i486 --with-tune=generic
    --enable-checking=release --build=i486-linux-gnu --host=i486-linux-gnu
    --target=i486-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)
```

My gcc is also automatically initializing variables. I want to disable it.

Did anyone face a similar issue, or have any idea about the solution?

Comment: May you should try `./a.out` ? (try `which a.out`)

Comment: I'm running ./a.out.  The code is working flawless.

Comment: Your example depends on the `segfault`ing due to failure to allocate memory. Check with `buf` points to after `malloc`. What is the output of `printf("%p\n", buf);` right after `malloc`?

Comment: printf("%p\n", buf); right after malloc is resulting in 0x37708008

Comment: That means that `malloc` call is successful. You should get something like `(nil)` indicating failure to allocate memory. You can try to allocate more memory in your program to different set of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The sample code only segfaults, if `malloc(1<<31)` fails, returning NULL. However, `malloc(1<<31)` succeeds if your system is able to allocate 2 gigs of memory without failing. That segfault example code snippet is from a time when systems could not typically allocate that amount of memory. Whether that succeeds or not depends on the amount of physical memory, on the amount of memory used up by other processes, and on the kernel's memory overcommit strategy, plus possibly on the (libc and) kernel versions used. So the different behaviour you see can be the result of different settings for the overcommit sysctl's, of the different set of processes running, or, obviously, of a different amount of physical memory.

From `/usr/src/linux/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting`:

```
The Linux kernel supports the following overcommit handling modes

0   -   Heuristic overcommit handling. Obvious overcommits of
        address space are refused. Used for a typical system. It
        ensures a seriously wild allocation fails while allowing
        overcommit to reduce swap usage.  root is allowed to 
        allocate slightly more memory in this mode. This is the 
        default.

1   -   Always overcommit. Appropriate for some scientific
        applications.

2   -   Don't overcommit. The total address space commit
        for the system is not permitted to exceed swap + a
        configurable percentage (default is 50) of physical RAM.
        Depending on the percentage you use, in most situations
        this means a process will not be killed while accessing
        pages but will receive errors on memory allocation as
        appropriate.

The overcommit policy is set via the sysctl `vm.overcommit_memory'.

The overcommit percentage is set via `vm.overcommit_ratio'.
```